# yii2 getting error in frontend module

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have yii2 project running with advanced template. I have created few modules for backend part and it works great, but now I need a module also for frontend, but I am getting error when trying to reach to it.

> ReflectionException
>
> ```
> Class frontend\modules\subscription\controllers\Module does not exist
> ```

I have this in my frontend main.php config file

```
..
   'modules' => [
        'subscription' => 'frontend\modules\subscription\Module'
    ],
...
```

and this is my urls

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                'plans' => 'site/plans',
                'subscribe' => 'subscription/subscribe/index',
                'subscription' => 'subscription/subscribe/subscription',
                'process-payment' => 'subscription/subscribe/process-payment',
                'payment-error' => 'subscription/subscribe/error',
            ],
        ],
```

and this is my Module.php file

```
<?php

namespace frontend\modules\subscription;

/**
 * subscription module definition class
 */
class Module extends \yii\base\Module
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public $controllerNamespace = 'frontend\modules\subscription\controllers';

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        // custom initialization code goes here
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Use `'subscription' => 'app\modules\subscription\Module'`

Comment: And, `public $controllerNamespace = 'app\modules\subscription\controllers';`

Comment: Class app\modules\subscription\controllers\Module does not exist

Comment: May be we need to change namespace like `namespace app\modules\subscription;`. Please incorporate all 3 changes and check once.

Comment: @NanaPartykar I have changed all, but no result, also don't forget that I am using advanced template

Comment: That is in my mind. But, configuration is same as basic yii2. So, don't worry. I think, `'modules' => [
    'subscription' => [
      'class' => 'app\modules\subscription\Module',
    ],` You forget to add `class` in **main.php**

Comment: Read this [Using Modules](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-modules.html#using-modules)

Comment: no result :( ....

Comment: I don't know why, but it searching Class in controllers directory app\modules\subscription\controllers\Module does not exist

Comment: I found it, there was a mistake in controller constructor, where it accepts Module object, I missed 'use'

Comment: Ok. Glad you found it. Keep coding.